# What is CHR code for single quote ' in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

What is CHR code for single quote (`'`) in oracle?
I am generating update statements ATM for tables without PKs, and Regex replacing some special characters.

```
select 'UPDATE QUESTION SET questiontypeid = '||questiontypeid||', questiontext = '''||questiontext||''', questiondescription = '''||questiondescription||''', productid = '||productid||', mandatory = '||CASE WHEN mandatory IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(mandatory) END ||', displayorder = '||displayorder||', minvalue = '||CASE WHEN minvalue IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(minvalue) END||', maxvalue = '||CASE WHEN maxvalue IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(maxvalue) END||', parentid = '||CASE WHEN parentid IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(parentid) END||', questioncategoryid = '||questioncategoryid||', isasset = '||CASE WHEN isasset IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(isasset) END||', ISTHUNDERHEADONLY = '||CASE WHEN ISTHUNDERHEADONLY IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE to_char(ISTHUNDERHEADONLY) END||', QCODE = '''||QCODE||''' WHERE QUESTIONID = '||QUESTIONID from (
(select * from question where questionid not in
(select t.questionid from question t
full join question@somecomp.co.uk d on t.questionid = d.questionid 
where t.questiontypeid <> d.questiontypeid
or t.questiontext <> d.questiontext
or t.questiondescription <> d.questiondescription
or t.productid <> d.productid
or t.mandatory <> d.mandatory
or t.displayorder <> d.displayorder
or t.minvalue <> d.minvalue
or t.maxvalue <> d.maxvalue
or t.parentid <> d.parentid
or t.questioncategoryid <> d.questioncategoryid
or t.isasset <> d.isasset))
)
```

Comment: There is nothing special about `'` in Oracle. It's the standard ASCII value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see the `ASCII` value :

```
SQL> select ascii('''') from dual;

ASCII('''')
-----------
         39
```

Or, to avoid multiple single-quotation marks, using literal quote technique :

```
SQL> select ascii(q'[']') from dual;

ASCII(Q'[']')
-------------
           39
```

Let's confirm :

```
SQL> select chr(39) from dual;

C
-
'

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name:

There is nothing special about `'` in Oracle. It's the standard ASCII value.

Answer is : `CHR(39)`